# In LOKI, how do you tell how much loki is being staked?

Tags: loki, staking, service-node

In Loki, how do you tell how much is being staked on the network? And how long does staking and unstaking take when you first activate it?

Comment: In all honesty, if you have questions regarding LOKI, you will be better off asking in their communities. The knowledge on this SE is heavily grounded in Monero.

Comment: Yeah, I'll ask there too, but maybe loki devs hang out here too. https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23731/are-questions-about-other-cryptonote-coins-on-topic

Comment: I understand it's a legitimate question and fork questions allowed. But to get an answer, you still need knowledgable people from those forks using this SE if you want answers to questions like this. As you will have discovered from your other questions r.e. LOKI, those people are not here.

Comment: https://lokidocs.com/#community-channels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the staking requirement is a known value, and the number of nodes active on the network is also known, you can calculate the minimum amount of Loki being staked on the network by simply multiplying the staking requirement by the node count. Let's take today for example:

Staking requirement (27137) * node count (465) = 12,618,705 Loki

The process of staking itself is explained in detail here https://lokidocs.com/ServiceNodes/SNFullGuide/

With the introduction of Infinite Staking, unlocking a Service Node takes 15 days. If your node goes down, it'll be unlocked in 30 days.

Comment: Unlocking as in releasing your coins to you? That seems like an awful alot of days to lock coins.